# Why i cannot use url redirecting with multiple GET elements?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to write URL with multiple get parameters.The parameters in my URL are 1)category name 2)latitude and 3)longitude. out of which the latitude and longitude is optional.

This is my htaccess redirect :

```
RewriteRule ^lists/([a-zA-z]+)/[^\d,.]/[^\d,.]/ lists.php?category=$1&latitude=$2&longitude=$3

This is my url to this page :
https://example.com/lists/cars/19.1905792/72.96778239999999

actual url : 
https://example.com/listAds.php?category=cars&lat=19.1905792&lng=72.96778239999999
```

Now here problem is

1) I am getting a 404 error page when i use this and the other problem

2)is that as i have mentioned that latitude and longitude are optional.. they give me error to when this two are not set.

I have already done the same thing on other pages with one GET request and works fine there.

Answer (score 1):

- You've made it match anything *but* numbers (the `^` at the start of the character list `\d`)
- You've not made the two numbers optional yet. `[^\d,.]` means it requires exactly one of those characters. And because it can only match one of digit comma or dot, you can't do decimals yet. If you want to quantify how many times, you would need to add `.` for one or more, `*` for zero or more, or do a range `{min,max}` after `[^\d,.]`.
- You're not capturing the two numbers even if they did match - missing `()`.
- You probably only want to match if both longitude and latitude are provided, not one or the other - missing grouping them both (but non-capturing).

Try regex testers like https://regex101.com/r/PtwC0b/4 Although in Apache I don't think you need to escape `/` with `\` so ignore the `\/`.

End result is *something* like `/lists/([a-zA-z]+)/(?:([\d.]+)/([\d.]+)/){0,1}`

The `(?: ... ){0,1}` group is non-capturing, but ensures everything in it is one group - ie only provide both longitude and latitude (and exactly zero or one sets of them). For a full explanation, see https://regex101.com/r/PtwC0b/4

[image: explanation from regex101.com]

This has not been tested for Apache.

Comment: RewriteRule ^lists/([a-zA-z]+)/(?:([\d.]+)/([\d.]+)/) lists.php?im=$1&latitude=$2&longitude=$3

This is the one made with your suggestion.. but not working??

Comment: You're missing the `{0,1}`. That aside, you've not described why it's not working. Does list.php get hit at all? which urls does not work with?,what are `$_REQUEST['latitude']` etc populated with if they are hit?, etc. Remember someone you don't know on the internet is trying to help you with your problem, try to provide as much information as possible to help them help you.
See 
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=ed312f92-3330-5ecd-9ade-95d342079ff0
Note that you _might_ need to escape & with \& in your destination.